# Failed to start clamd.service: Unit clamd.service not found

Tags: antivirus, clamav

I have installed clamav and it's affiliated files (and clamtk). However, I keep getting the error message:

```
Failed to start clamd.service: Unit clamd.service not found.
```

I get the error when I run

```
sudo service clamd start
```

I have tried many different things but can't find any answer online. Any solutions?

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Where are you seeing this clamd.service not found error at?  Also, what version of Ubuntu are you using?  Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1190931/edit) your question and add this info.

Comment: Clamd is actually `clamav-daemon`.  `systemctl status clamav-daemon.service` should show you that it is running.

Comment: Now that seems to have did it! Thanks a lot!